# Batch Search combo Z: Test List

Tags: batch-file

```
 for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%a in ('dir "recordings.txt" /s /b') do (
  echo %%a
 )
```

Is this the correct format to look on the Z: drive for files in the recordings.txt?

Tried powershell don't have permissions on the server

Contents of the file just have the file name / extension
3030009948_3030009912_df1389947f0fb80d62832122.sasf

The Directory structure of Z: is as follows
MM\dd\hh\mm\

recordings.txt is on the Desktop of my userprofile
I also need the paths of the found files

Comment: Do you want to find every `recordings.txt` in a tree?  or is there just one?

Comment: There are 9000+ items in the recordings text file, I need to search for each on in Z: and the output the full path of the location to a text file so each file should only be present in one location it is an archiving location for files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should read `recordings.txt` on your desktop and create `recordings-results.txt` in the same place with the `full path to every file` inside it.

```
@echo off
dir /b /s /a-d "z:\" >"%temp%\results.tmp"
del "%userprofile%\desktop\recordings-results.txt" 2>nul

for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("%userprofile%\desktop\recordings.txt") do (
    echo finding "%%a"
    findstr /i /c:"%%a" "%temp%\results.tmp" >>"%userprofile%\desktop\recordings-results.txt"
)

del "%temp%\results.tmp"
pause
```

This should be even faster:

```
@echo off
dir /b /s /a-d "z:\" >"%temp%\results.tmp"
findstr /i /g:"%userprofile%\desktop\recordings.txt" "%temp%\results.tmp" >"%userprofile%\desktop\recordings-results.txt"
del "%temp%\results.tmp"
pause
```

Comment: The edited code has another version which may be better.

Answer (score 1):

`Dir` is to look into a directory if you want to get a value from a file use :

```
 for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('type "Z:\recordings.txt"') do (
  echo %%a
 )
```

Comment: thanks updated my original question to be more specific